# how can i select item from option menu if i have one item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to select an item from option select menu when I have just one item in order to use in my next function ( $('#').on("change", function() {}) )

it's work when I have more than one item in the menu but if there is one item when I clicking on that one item there is no any result:

from the backend  item one=[1] two=[1,2] and three=[1,2,3], it is ok for selecting two and three but not for item one which I have only one number inside

HTML

```
<select id = "fir">
<option>one</option>
<option>two</option>
<option>three</option>
</select>

<select id="sec" >
<option ></option>
</select>

<input id="tbl_S2"  type="text" >
```

JavaScript

```
$('#fir').on("click", function() {
  var schem =$("#fir").val();

    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:'url/'+schem,
    success:function(data2){
        $("#sec").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
        $("#sec").append("<option>"+data2[i]+"</option>");
       }
      }
    }                  
   },
  });
});


$('#fir').on("change", function() {
     $('#sec').on("change", function() {

           $('#tbl_S2').html( "hello");

     });
});
```

Comment: If you have only one item in a menu, it will automatically be selected.

Comment: where's test2,  and where is data2 assigned to my-text?

Comment: Please could you add your HTML snippet too and describe what happens to `test2` when you select certain option from `sec`? And hence, what would you like to happen instead? Best to create a jsfiddle, if you possibly can... Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for a particular item to be selected, you should use the `option selected` method, i.e. append `selected` after data2[i] *if there is only one item in the list.* (add an if statement)

Your if statement would look similar to this:

```
if (data2.length == 1){
     $("#sec").append("<option selected>"+data2[i]+"</option>");
  }
else{
  for (var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
     $("#sec").append("<option>"+data2[i]+"</option>");
  }
}
```

The HTML output would look something like this

```
<select>
<option value="data" selected>Your variable</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps

EDIT:

The below snippet is a simple example of how to show both values from two dropdowns, even when one only has one item in the dropdown. Please note that in the example, if the second dropdown is changed (if you un-comment back in the second option), the output text doesn't change until the other dropdown is clicked. I'm sure I could have corrected this with a little more time spent. There is a [jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/dafilayuwe/edit?html,js,output)

I am aware that your list is not static, but dynamic, that you are using ajax to populate, however I hope this provides a starting point.

```js
var secSelect= "";

function showSelect(str) {
  var schem1="";
  var returnText="";
  var schem1= str;  
  var sec1=document.getElementById("sec");
  var hello=document.getElementById("text1");
  var sec2=sec1.value;
  
  if (secSelect !=""){
    sec1=secSelect;
  } 
 
  hello.innerHTML = " hello";
  returnText= schem1 +" " +sec2 + hello.value;
  document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = returnText;
};  

function passSelect(str2){
  secSelect=str2;
}
```

```css
#text1{background-color:white!important;
     width:150px;
  display:inline-block;
  height:13.5px;
  vertical-align:top;}
#sec, #fir{display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<select id="fir" onclick="showSelect(this.value);">
<option>one</option>
<option>two</option>
<option>three</option>
</select>

<select id="sec" onclick="passSelect(this.value);">
<option>one</option>
<!--<option>rach</option>-->
</select>

<textarea id="text1" type="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: If there's only 1 option in the menu, it's selected by default.

Comment: @Barmar then why can't he select it?

Comment: @Barmar the option selected is good to know for future reference anyway

Comment: I have no idea what the question means. The `selected` attribute just controls which one is initially selected, not whether the user can select it.

Comment: actually, after selecting an item from the menu I want to use it in this function   $('#sec').on("change", function() {}) which I can't select an item when I have just one item in the list, so I must click one item but it's not work

Comment: @Alex that wasn't the question.. post your accurate question (i.e. including the change function and update your description to describe the actual problem).. then we can help you.

Comment: @Alex not enough!

Comment: @Alex if you are reading the select values from a db, then have a look at this example http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_database.asp (I really dislike pointing to w3schools, but the example and explanation are good..)  The way you have your ajax call integrated into your js doesn't look right to me, and gives syntax errors [in jsbin etc..]. Other examples on the page also.